# Issues related to after deployment of Website on IIS server from Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

**Step 1:** I have pushed all files for my website on TFS. The files are shown in the below screenshot after getting pushed on TFS:

**Screenshot:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6zlT.png

**Step 2:** I have created a Build definition and generated the artifact, then I have created a Release definition and after successful deployment i am able to see some of the Artifacts file on "Physical Location" (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestVSTSWebsite) of my computer.

**Requirement:** But what i want is to get my all files on the defined "Physical Location" that i pushed on TFS.

As for now i am getting the following artifact files on my physical location as shown in the below screenshots:

**Screenshot[1]:**  https://i.stack.imgur.com/614U3.png

**Screenshot[2]:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBD14.png

**Edited:** I have used the Copy Files task in the build definition with all the fields defined in the below screenshot:

**Screenshot:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6eXk.png

But even after successful build the the files are not visible when i use the Copy File task in my Release definition to deploy the project and when i click on the [...] near the Source Folder i get the following folders as show in below screenshot without the contents of Target folder that i defined in the Build definition.

**Screenshot**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/76mP2.png

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to have all your source in the "Physical Location". You need to copy all files in `$(build.sourcesdirectory)` to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` in your **Build** definition.

1. Make sure you have mapped all your source:

[image]

2. In your build definition, copy all files in `$(build.sourcesdirectory)` to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`:

[image]

Comment: In the build definition, I have copied all files in $(build.sourcesdirectory) to $(build.artifactstagingdirectory). The build was successful. Now which task should i add in my "Release definition" to get/deploy all the files on my computer's "Physical location" ?

Comment: Since all sources are published to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`, now in Release definition, you need to add a `Copy Files` task and select the source in `Source Folder` parameter.

Comment: I have added the Copy files task in the Release definition. I have edited the question by attaching the screenshots. Can you please check ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to check whether you have copied all files you want in  $(build.artifactstagingdirectory), and whether you have linked the correct version of artifact.

Comment: Actually I am new to VSTS, so can you please tell me where can I find $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) ? Is it on my computer or on VSTS ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` is the local path on the agent where any artifacts are copied to before being pushed to their destination. For example: `c:\agent\_work\1\a`. You don't have to use `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`, the target folder can be defined by yourself.